# How can I get OS info from Amazon instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

is it any way to get OS from Amazon Instance using Java API?
there are methods platform - but it returns only "Windows" or null, even if I get Windows how I can figure out what kind of Os family it is - like Windows, windows + sql standard, windows + websql, windows + sql enterprice
The same about linux - I didn't find a way to get info - is it ubuntu or redhat

Comment: No, only option is to get platform for windows machines, but it's not helpful at all

Answer (score 0):

There is no Amazon EC2 API call to see "inside" the Amazon EC2 instance. However, you can **obtain information about the AMI used to launch the instance**.

Here's an example, using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which makes similar API calls to Java.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].ImageId' --filter Name=instance-id,Values=i-xxxxxxxx --output text
ami-d9fe9be3

$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-d9fe9be3
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm", 
            "Name": "amzn-ami-hvm-2014.03.2.x86_64-ebs", 
            "Hypervisor": "xen", 
            "ImageOwnerAlias": "amazon", 
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple", 
            "ImageId": "ami-d9fe9be3", 
            "State": "available", 
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-c90a03fd", 
                        "VolumeSize": 8, 
                        "VolumeType": "standard", 
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "Architecture": "x86_64", 
            "ImageLocation": "amazon/amzn-ami-hvm-2014.03.2.x86_64-ebs", 
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs", 
            "OwnerId": "137112412989", 
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda", 
            "CreationDate": "2014-06-11T19:46:45.000Z", 
            "Public": true, 
            "ImageType": "machine", 
            "Description": "Amazon Linux AMI x86_64 HVM EBS"
        }
    ]
}
```

Information can be extracted from the `Description` field. However, please note that **Windows AMIs are deprecated each month** as updates are made available by Microsoft. This means that old Windows instances might not have information accessible about their AMIs.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same info - and if AMI doesn't contain description - there is no way to determine what kind of OS is inside. How Amazon determines amount of money they suppose to charge for some vm - if the is no any way to get it with their API?

Comment: There is hidden information associated with disk images that identifies the Operating System. This information is associated with disks when they are created, and is used to determine on-going charging.